# Cake PHP complex find 'OR' is not working properly with null and empty string

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Cake PHP complex find 'OR' opertor is not working properly with null...

```
$conditions = array(
    'Person.id' => array(2, 4, 1, 23, 45, 11),
    'OR' => array(
    array(
        array('NOT' => array('Person.image' => null)),
        array('NOT' => array('Person.image' => '')),
    ),
    array(
        array('NOT' => array('Person.photos' => null)),
        array('NOT' => array('Person.photos' => '')),
    )
    )
);
```

The corresponding cake sql dump output query as below

```
SELECT `Person`.`id`, `Person`.`created`, `Person`.`modified` 
FROM `people` AS `Person` WHERE `Person`.`id` IN (2, 4, 1, 23, 45, 11)  AND 
((((NOT (`Person`.`image` IS NULL)) AND (NOT (`Person`.`image` = NULL))))   OR 
(((NOT (`Person`.`photos` IS NULL)) AND (NOT (`Person`.`photos` = ''))))) 
ORDER BY FIELD(`Person`.`id`, 2, 4, 1, 23, 45, 11) ASC LIMIT 3
```

In cake condition array, I have given `Person.image` is not `null` or `''`, but corresponding cake sql outputs as `(NOT (Person.image IS NULL)) AND (NOT (Person.image = NULL))` where it should be like `(NOT (Person.image IS NULL)) AND (NOT (Person.image = ''))` .

Here **`Person.image`** both are compared with NULL itself(**IS NULL** and **= NULL**), where **Person.image = NULL** want to compared with empty string like **Person.image = ''**.

Here `'Person.image'` is `'INT'` and `'Person.photos'` is `'VARCHAR'` of type, but it is difficult to change type from current stage.

How it can be corrected ?

Comment: It looks like you have some inconsistency in your DB-schema. As you can see, Cake generates the right query for the `photos` field. Can you provide us more details about the fields and more important the specific field types (e.g. varchar(50), int, char, ...)?

Moreover I would consider re-checking how you're saving your data, as checking for null AND for empty values could hide some nasty errors (however, is completely legit and can be usefully in some cases).

Comment: @boast: `Person.image` is `INT` and `Person.photos` is `VARCHAR` of type. Here `Person.image` can be saved with a value after that we can edit the form and save it without a value. So there will be empty string at that time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not forced to use an associative array to define conditions. You can define it like so:

```
$conditions = array(
    'Person.id' => array(2, 4, 1, 23, 45, 11),
    'OR' => array(
    array(
        array('NOT' => array('Person.image' => null)),
        array('NOT' => array('Person.image = "" ')),
    ),
    array(
        array('NOT' => array('Person.photos' => null)),
        array('NOT' => array('Person.photos = "" ')),
    )
    )
);
```

Comment: Your solution is working fine, but I can't understand 'not forced to use an associative array to define conditions'. Here 'Person.image' to null is working fine, but why 'Person.image' to empty string is failing. Both uses same structure...

Comment: ('Person.image = "" ') is not an associative array, just a statement. What is important is that my solution works :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is an issue with interpreting `'Person.image <>' => null`, since it is not strictly valid SQL (at least not in MySQL).

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html):

> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL.

You could try replacing it with a negated null comparison:

```
array('NOT' => array('Person.image' => null))
```

Aside from that, your last two `OR` operators does nothing, since you only have one statement in each. Is your array nesting what you ment it to be? If you add newlines and indentation, your code becomes

```
$conditions = array(
    'Person.id' => array(2, 4, 1, 23, 45, 11),
    'OR' => array(
        array(
            'OR' => array(
                'Person.image <>' => null
            ),
            array(
                'Person.image <>' => ''
            )
        ),
        array(
            'OR' => array(
                'Person.photos <>' => ''
            ),
            array(
                'Person.photos <>' => null
            )
        )
    )
);
```

...which looks weird.

The full change would be:

```
$conditions = array(
    'Person.id' => array(2, 4, 1, 23, 45, 11),
    'OR' => array(
        array(
            array('NOT' => array('Person.image' => null)),
            array('NOT' => array('Person.image' => '')),
        ),
        array(
            array('NOT' => array('Person.photos' => null)),
            array('NOT' => array('Person.photos' => '')),
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: `((((NOT (Person.default_image IS NULL)) AND (NOT (Person.default_image = NULL)))) OR (((NOT (Person.photos IS NULL)) AND (NOT (Person.photos = '')))))` , this is OR condition in cake by above code, here also  `(Person.default_image = NULL)` not `(Person.default_image = '')` .

Comment: What is this Person.default_image ? It is not mentioned anywhere before. If you only post a snippet of the actual code and output, you should say so, since you might have gotten the wrong pieces.

Comment: Sorry, It's image itself not default_image..  `((((NOT (Person.image IS NULL)) AND (NOT (Person.image = NULL)))) OR (((NOT (Person.photos IS NULL)) AND (NOT (Person.photos = '')))))`

Comment: What is it you actually want? The output matches the condition perfectly now.

Comment: `(NOT (Person.image IS NULL)) AND (NOT (Person.image = NULL))` I want above code as `(NOT (Person.image IS NULL)) AND (NOT (Person.image = ''))` . Here `''` want to substitute in place `NULL`. But here it is  (NOT (Person.image = NULL)) ...

Comment: 'NULL is to assume that it is not possible to insert a zero or an empty string'    from [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) you provided. Here I want to check whether an image is null or empty string. But in sql `Person.image` checked with NULL only, not empty string.

Comment: What column type is Person.image? Is it diffrent from Person.photos, which seems to work fine?

Comment: It seems then that CakePHP understands that you can't compare an INT to an empty string, and compares it to an NULL instead. Your code makes no sense. Just remove the 'Person.image' => '' check.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Cake's null comparison depends on the database field type.  If your field is of type integer then Cake will redefine '' as Null.  Varchars will not be redefined.

Are you able to go to MySQL and change the Person.image type to varchar?

If so remember to clear your cache in app/tmp/cache/models for Cake to register changes.

**UPDATE: manually changing the schema type will force cake to treat a field type as defined.  So something like this prior to the query will work:**

```
$this->Person->_schema['image']['type']='string';
```

Comment: It is difficult to change the **Person.image** type from current stage. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Manually force the column type via the schema.  Before the query:  `$this->Person->_schema['image']['type']='string';`

Comment: Your solution is working fine. But I am confused, which way I want to go  'kaklon suggestion' `array('NOT' => array('Person.image = "" ')` is also working fine..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, those answers are in my opinion not 100% right, they provide workarounds but no solution.

The problem are the database column types:

> `Person.image` is `INT` and `Person.photos` is `VARCHAR` of type

Well, `''` (the empty string) is not a valid value for an integer, ever. I assume you have allowed `NULL` values on the `Person.image` column, so cake does the right job!

It just doesn't make any sense to ask if an integer field has the value of the empty string, it can only be `NULL`, 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, etc. (if signed).

What happens here is that cake knows about your data structure (note the `DESCRIBE` queries when the `debug` flag is > 0), so it tries to correct your statement to the next useful one - testing for `NULL` values. Moreover, even if you ask MySQL (or force cake doing so) to query your DB, there will *never* be any effect because of this condition (maybe because of the other ones):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE my_int_column = ''` is completely legit SQL but will always return 0 results whereas `SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT(my_int_column = '')` will always return all results.

Conclusion: if your app works by now with the `=''` condition, it will work exactly the same without the condition.

Final note: However, you can `INSERT` the empty string into an integer column and it will be converted by MySQL to `0`, so you might want to check for those.